# What is the purpose of 'R'?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

Throughout my project i have adding buttons or clickable image buttons. However i have no idea why I am using 'R' before the .id.example. I have enquired online but nothing can give me a clear answer. Can anyone explain?

```
private Button DisplayRoutineButton;
private Button ClearRoutineButton;

private static int ImageID = 0;

ImageView activityslotlocationa, activityslotlocationb, activityslotlocationc, activityslotlocationd, activityslotlocatione, activityslotlocationf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.routineeditscreen);

    myDb = new Database(this);

    DisplayRoutineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.displayroutinebutton);
    ClearRoutineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearroutinebutton);

    // Display Routine Button
    DisplayRoutineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Display Schedule");
            Intent i = new Intent(MondayRoutineEdit.this, MondayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Monday Routine Display");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Delete Routine Button
    ClearRoutineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Delete Routine");
            deleteRoutine();
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Routine Deleted");
        }
    });

    // Audio Feedback
    ImageView artactivity = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.artactivityimage);
    final MediaPlayer artsoundeffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.art);
    artactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            artsoundeffect.start();
        }
    });

    ImageView bedtimestoryactivity = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.bedtimestoryactivityimage);
    final MediaPlayer bedtimestorysoundeffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bedtimestory);
    bedtimestoryactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bedtimestorysoundeffect.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: "R" stands for "Resource". You should have googled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R.java is the dynamically generated class, created during build process to dynamically identify all assets (from strings to android widgets to layouts), for usage in java classes in Android app.

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html), for more details.